# DHTMLX schedule.load doesn't work until xml file

Tags: php, dhtmlx

I use DHTMLX's scheduler plugin.
when i config the `scheduler.load()`. Does it support xml file only?
i use php echo the same format data,but it's doesn't work.
scheduler.load('1.xml') it's ok.
but i use scheduler.load('1.php') it's doesn't work.

i don't generated xml file.i only use php echo:

```
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";
    echo "<data>";
    foreach($this->info as $value) {
        echo "<event id='".$value->reg->getStamp()."'>";
        echo "<start_date>".$value->reg->getDate()." ".$value->reg->getStartTime()."</start_date>";
        echo "<end_date>".$value->reg->getDate()." ".$value->reg->getEndTime()."</end_date>";
        echo "<text>".$value->reg->getTitle()."</text>";
        echo "<details>预约人:".$value->reg->sfGuardUser->getFirstName()."</details>";
        echo "</event>";
    }
    echo "</data>";
```

my php echo the data like this:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><data><event id='1'><start_date>2011-12-16 05:00:00</start_date><end_date>2011-12-16 06:00:00</end_date><text>aaaa</text><details>register: lee</details></event></data>`

my dhtmlx like this:

```
scheduler.load("/ajax/equRegInfo?equipmentid=874");
```

Comment: Impossible to answer without more details. Maybe the XML generated by your PHP is invalid (you cannot just paste XML into a .php file due to the `<?xml` header which you need to `echo` inside a PHP tag to avoid issues with `<?` starting PHP mode)

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between outputting XML via a php script and using an XML file. This implies, that your XML file doesn't look exactly as you imagine.  Here is what I would do:

Load your .php file in a browser, outside of the scheduler.  Check out the XML.  You should see the differences.

I also notice, you are using unicode characters.  XML required [!CDATA[....]] construction for those.

Answer (score 1):

It is very very important you tell PHP what to serve the data as. Change this line:

```
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";
```

To this:

```
header('Content-type: text/xml');
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";
// rest of script follows...
```

Make sure that you set the `content-type` before you `echo` *anything* out to the page.